# .NET Upgrade Assistant - support for .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

in .NET MAUI Roadmap from 24th of May was mentioned that there will be full support of .NET Upgrade Assistant for .NET MAUI (conversion from Xamarin -> .NET MAUI) around the same time as VS 17.3 will come up. VS 17.3 has been released on 9th August, but I can't find any new information about .NET Upgrade Assistant. Could anyone please provide me some new info or at least redirect me to some articles/documentation?

Especially I am interested if there are new things in auto migration of XAML and API naming ( (names of XAML tags, naming as Color.Red to Colors.Red etc.), because the old capability of .NET Upgrade Assistant was only to auto migrate the solution files, target frameworks and just a few things actually... :/

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/issues You can ask the developers directly.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately without any response (and it has been more than a week). :/

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin to MAUI Upgrade assistant is on the roadmap for .Net 7. Visual Studio 17.3 released with general MAUI tooling not with the upgrade experience.

You can see the MAUI Roadmap at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap

You can follow MAUI conversion issues in the [upgrade-assistant repo with the area:Maui tag](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/labels/area%3AMaui)

You can track converting the Colors class at [Upgrade the Colors API to reflect .NET MAUI changes #592](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/issues/592)

Comment: Yea thanks. I have found these pages as well, I was hoping maybe for some more official/detailed roadmaps or information. But I guess it is all it is. Even the msdn docu of MAUI seems a little bit cheap. :/